# windws phone 8, how to build a list that mix up list and grid mode with LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

hi I'm working for a WP8 application, now I'm going to present a irregular list, for item's template is not unified. Just like a LongListSelector contains list and grid mode in it, seems complex a little bit, can anyone give some sparks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can have multiple item templates, it is explained here in detail: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector

However if you don't need/want that complex control, then XAML value converters could be the way to go. This way you can customize each item differently based on values from bound classes. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-25-Advanced-Binding-with-Value-Converters

Comment: I have seen this post before and used this approach for certain situations, actually what still confused me is how to merge the list and grid layout mode in one LongListSelector. for example, sometimes the items are horizontal and sometimes are vertical in different groups. I'm gonna find a best approach to implement this kind of layout, smooth experience and visualization are required.